# gulp ругается на знак деления в scss

Tags: html, css, scss

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(494, 1240)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

╷
37 │         flex: 0 0 494 / 1240 * 100%;
│                   ^^^^^^^^^^
╵
#src\scss\header.scss 37:13  @import
#src\scss\style.scss 80:9    root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(29, 24)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

╷
45 │         line-height: 29 / 24 * 100%;
│                      ^^^^^^^
╵
#src\scss\header.scss 45:16  @import
#src\scss\style.scss 80:9    root stylesheet

```
&__logo {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29 / 24 * 100%;
    color: #333;

}

&__main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 0 494 / 1240 * 100%;
}
```

Ругается на то, что знак деления устарел, по рекомендации галпа записал через math, но он опять засыпал ошибками, что можно сделать?

Comment: «записал через math» — как записали? «он опять засыпал ошибками» — какими ошибками? По ссылке из текста ошибки ходили?

Comment: только сейчас заметил, что недоглядел при записи, забыл вместо / поставить запятую

Comment: https://www.sassmeister.com/  это прекрасно собирает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
&__logo {
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: math.div(29, 24) * 100%;
color: #333;
```

}

```
&__main {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex: 0 0 math.div(494, 1240) * 100%;
```

}

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]